# Proxy all requests : Linux

Tags: linux, http-proxy

Like proxifier in Windows, can I intercept all tcp requests in Linux and pass it through a proxied connection.

Comment: a package called *badvpn* has a program called `tun2socks`. in linux the best way to capture *all tcp requests* is a tunnel.  what OS or protocol is the remote host running?  there are a lot of options.

Comment: I'll say my exact situation :
My connection to internet is through proxy(http squid with user auth basic). And I cannot apply proxy settings everywhere in linux. So like proxifier in windows the setup should be lisstening all TCP requests and Forward it through a preauthenticated proxy tunnel

Answer (score 2):

There are various solutions for this:

#### 1. Configuring http_proxy variables

You can set `$http_proxy` and other such variables. Most applications will pick this variable automatically. To set it system-wide, you can set this variable in either your `~/.bashrc` file or `/etc/profile`. Set it as:

```
http_proxy=http://user:password@proxyserver.com:3128
https_proxy=https://user:password@proxyserver.com:3128
export http_proxy
export https_proxy
```

#### 2. Using proxy_chains

Some applications would not use your proxy variable and they might not even have settings to use a proxy server. In such a case, you can direct all your PC traffic through a proxy server by using `proxy_chains`.

I've never used `proxy_chains`, however their homepage seems to tell it all in one single page: http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/howto.html

#### 3. Using transparent proxy

To force all your PC connection through a proxy, you can also use transparent proxy as an alternative to proxy_chains. I don't have much idea how to set this up (*I did this a long time back though and it worked!*) so you'll have to look on your own.